# Retrieve total for all months if not data exists but months should be within two dates only

Tags: mysql, date

First, I did see answers in SO that are related to my question and did get the design idea of tblmonths from them. But am stack with this:

Basically, I want to specify start and end dates as: 2015-05-01 And 2016-01-01. I want to get records between those dates based on month. If no data exists for a month between those, it should return 0.

So far my query returns correct data but always for 12 months even when the dates are a few months apart. For the period 2015-10-01 AND 2016-01-01, the output should be:

```
2015-Oct = 10
2015-Nov =  0
2015-Dec = 5
2016-Jan = 2
```

---

```
SELECT 
 tblmonths.monthid,
 COUNT(servicestatusid) as totalcompleted 
FROM  tblmonths 
left JOIN tblservicestatus ON  (tblmonths.monthid=MONTH(tblservicestatus.statusupdatedon) 
AND  tblservicestatus.statusupdatedon BETWEEN 2015-10-01 AND 2016-01-01) 
GROUP  BY  monthid
```

I have moved the:

```
tblservicestatus.statusupdatedon BETWEEN 2015-10-01 AND 2016-01-01
```

out of the LEFT JOIN but no change and included it as HAVING after the GROUP BY clause.

Someone suggested I do it over the monthid field and I came up with:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(servicestatusid) as totalcompleted 
FROM tblmonths 
LEFT JOIN tblservicestatus ON (tblmonths.monthid=MONTH(tblservicestatus.statusupdatedon) 
AND CONCAT_WS("-",2015,monthid,1) BETWEEN 2015-10-01 AND 2016-01-01) 
GROUP BY monthid
```

Wondering if CONCAT_WS was returning string, did try STR_TO_DATE. The only change that makes some change is changing the JOIN but the output is wrong.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Typically, you would handle the logic of missing dates in the presentation layer, assuming that's available

Comment: @Strawberry thats an option but it is going to be an overkill but let me try it. thanks.